# Prevent DOM refresh with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm aware this probably indicates a fundamental understand of the way Vue.js operates, but here goes...

I have an application using Vue.js in which there is a simple countdown, updating every second to show the time until an event starts. Every second, this causes a refresh of the DOM, meaning that any methods involved in e.g. determining classes, etc., are run, which is inefficient. But more importantly, it causes any tooltips which are displaying to flicker every second.

So my question is, is there a way I can do this countdown timer, which is within a div managed by Vue.js, which doesn't involve a refresh of everything else on the page? Isolate it, somehow?

Comment: Share your working code ?

Comment: I'm hoping there's an answer from general principles. It would take me hours to isolate a bit of code to reproduce this.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-sunset-vm1te?file=/src/App.vue is this what you want?

Comment: I have a fully working countdown clock. Actually, you can see it at https://virtualrelay.norfolkgazelles.co.uk/leaderboard. What I am trying to avoid is what happens when you mouse over e.g. 'Dereham Runners AC' - the tooltip is being refreshed every second, which I don't want.

Comment: Now I understand your question.

Comment: I don't think it should refresh the tooltips, can you share your minimum code for the logic behind the countdown timer?

Comment: All code should be visible in the example. The issue is not specific to this, though, it's a more fundamental question. I have a countdown timer which is only ever going to be impacting one element in the DOM. Is it possible to isolate this somehow? If it were outside the div which is under Vue.js control it would be straightforward.

Comment: I think you are calling a function which is changing tooltip. share your component code here.

Comment: The current Vue v2.x always re-renders the whole template even if only a tiny part of it is affected by a reactive change in your data model. The only way to prevent this before v3.x is out is to split your template into as many sub-components as possible **AND** reasonable (too many components is also not good).

Comment: @NikleshRaut, common.js contains the directive for the tooltips.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, presumably if I avoided any reactive change in the countdown timer, then it would not need to do this refresh, then? So, basically, handle it all with e.g. jQuery (or straight Javascript) without using data at all.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, surely the virtual DOM only updates the actual parts of the real DOM that have changed? Opening the browser's dev tools on the page the OP linked, it shows that only very minimal parts of the page are being updated.

Comment: @NilsonJacques I meant this - https://slides.com/akryum/vueconfus-2019#/4/0/3 Did you mean the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is a simple enough one, once you get a clear view of the question. The problem is occurring because I am using reactive data to display the timer - `{{countdownMessage}}`. So when any change occurs to that reactive data, all reactive data everywhere is checked. So the secret here is to leave that as an empty div and use `document.getElementById("countdown").innerHtml=msg` as the last line of the method which builds the message, instead of assigning the value to data.

I'm so used to thinking in Vue.js terms for all display of changing data that I forget that sometimes other techniques might prove necessary instead.

Comment: It must be something with the way your code is written, because it's possible to do it without the tooltips re-rendering. See the example I put together: https://codesandbox.io/s/countdown-timer-example-f7bqf?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: @NilsonJacques, that's very interesting. I'll study that to see what is done differently. Thanks for putting the time in.